# PHP isset for optional field data – Undefined index

Tags: php

I'm passing form data into an email to be sent via the server (in this case I am using SendGrid but I think this related specifically to PHP, not the API) and I have a repeatable job section on the form. They can add more than one job on the form to fill out and if they do it simply clones the fields and prepends each field label/name and id with an integer, for example, `wh-company2` and `wh-company2` and so on. They can add a maximum of 10 jobs.

I'm then passing this into my email template that is being sent. All is well but when it comes to the job section I want to do a check so if `wh-company8` exists for example, then it returns the 8 jobs data.

```
<?php for ($count = 1; $count <= 10; $count++) : ?>
    <?php if (isset($submitted_data['wh-company' . $count . '\''])) : ?>
        <p><strong>Work History <?php echo $count; ?></strong><br/>
        Company: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-company' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/>  
        Position: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-position' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/>    
        Company address: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-address-1' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/>    
        Date worked from: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-date-started' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/>    
        Date worked until: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-date-ended' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/> 
        Reasons for leaving: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-reasons-you-left' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/> 
        Referee name(s): <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-referee-name' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/> 
        Referee position: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-referee-position' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/>    
        Referee phone number: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-referee-telephone' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/>   
        Referee email: <?php echo $submitted_data['wh-referee-email' . $count . '\'']; ?><br/></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

This is what I have so far. I didn't have `isset` and rather just `if ($submitted_data['wh-company' . $count . '\'']) :` but it returned an `Notice: Undefined index` error for each of the 10 items. I then included the `isset` but now doesn't return anything.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding this '\'' ?

Comment: the \ is to escape the `'`, however, adding the `'` character to the end of index string does seem a little interesting.  This is probably what is causing all of the indices to be incorrect in the first place.

Comment: Post your HTML form to see the field names.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Thanks for the feedback. I need to iterate through $submitted_data['wh-company']; then adding the $count to the end of each one. I can't see how else to do it?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez The form is really large. This is just one piece.

Comment: Just don't append the ' the the end of the indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no else statement.  This means that `isset` is returning false, the html snippet is skipped and the next iteration of the loop is executed.  Because every single `isset` is failing, noted by the fact that you stated

> it returned an Notice: Undefined index error for each of the 10 items

there is no ouptut.

**EDIT**

As noted in a comment, adding the `'` character is what is causing the `Undefined index error` while `isset` is performing its task perfectly, simply use the following:

```
<?php if (isset($submitted_data['wh-company' . $count])) : ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` for fields that repeat in a form so they become an array when sent to PHP, and you don't need to worry about adding indexes to the new fields. Here is an example, copy-paste next code in a PHP file an open it in your browser (type something in the job `<input>` fields) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_job ()
{ var jobs = document.getElementById("jobs"); // <DIV>.
  jobs.innerHTML += "<br/>" + // ◄■■ ADD NEW <INPUT> INSIDE <DIV>.
                    "Enter job <input type='text' name='job[]'/>"; // ◄■■ JOB[]
}
</script>


<form method="post"> <!-- ◄■■ FORM WILL REFRESH BECAUSE NO ACTION DEFINED -->
  <button type="button" onclick="add_job()">Add job</button>
  <br/>
  <div id="jobs"></div> <!-- ◄■■ DIV FOR THE JOBS -->
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit jobs"/>
</form>


<?php 
if ( isset( $_POST["job"] ) ) // ◄■■ IF PAGE REFRESHED (FORM SUBMISSION).
   { echo "Entered jobs: ";
     foreach ( $_POST["job"] as $job ) // ◄■■ "JOB" IS THE NAME OF THE <INPUT>S.
       echo $job . " ";
   }
?>
```

The logic is simple : when the button `Add job` is clicked one new `<input>` is added to the `<div>`, when the form is submitted PHP gets the jobs as an array and displays them. Notice all the `<input>`s have the same name : "job[]", and PHP will recognize them as "job" (an array).